# node.js memory leak apparently caused by string.replace() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace, memory-leaks

I am trying to fix a memory leak in node.js. I have found a couple useful [tutorials](https://www.alexkras.com/simple-guide-to-finding-a-javascript-memory-leak-in-node-js/) for diagnosing problems, but I'm having trouble *fixing* the issue. My program runs a cronjob every couple minutes, updates a variable called siteBody based on what it scrapes, and does stuff with that new variable. At one point, I replace some characters in siteBody, and I notice that there's a substantial difference in heap usage before and after this command:

```
var heapUsed = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;
console.log("BEFORE: Program is using "+heapUsed+" bytes of Heap.");

//replace all newline character with blanks
siteBody = siteBody.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

var heapUsed = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;
console.log("AFTER: Program is using "+heapUsed+" bytes of Heap.");
```

Any ideas what could be causing this or what I can do to fix it?

This is how I am implementing the cronjob:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  var date = new Date();
  if (   
  date.getSeconds() == 0 
  ){    searchAndUpdate();    }
}, null, true);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Memory use growing once doesn’t indicate a leak. If you repeat the operation, does it grow unbounded? (I can’t imagine it does – this is a very straightforward operation.)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Every time the Cronjob repeats, the numbers output by these (and other) logs steadily increase until they outstrip my capacity. So, I'm still looking for the leak.

Comment: What are you using to implement this “cronjob”? Not a crontab I suppose, since the Node process continues running, but some library?

Comment: Agreeing with @Ryan -- I would be _very_ surprised to find that a relatively innocuous core string method contained a memory leak.  Not to say it is impossible, but I would certainly investigate other potential culprits first.

Comment: @Ryan thanks. I thought this might be a culprit because *each* time the process runs it is increasing substantially at this and other steps, but I know now that is not exactly what I should be looking for. I have updated my post with the CronJob info asked for. I will keep looking - let me know if I should close this. Thanks

Comment: You're also measuring the memory used BEFORE garbage collection has been allowed to run and you need to be looking at heap snapshots, not total process memory usage to see what is actually using memory.

Comment: Thanks all. Running into a heap of trouble trying to install heapdump (first needed Python now something about Microsoft.cpp.default.props) so I'm going to take a break and come back later

Comment: I think I found the memory leak elsewhere - let me know if I should close this q or answer it or something. Thank you

Comment: @garson May I know, where you found the memory leak, Because even I am using a cron job and replace function. My memory is increasing at a low pace. After a day, it goes above 1GB

Comment: I found it elsewhere in the code I was running, the searchAndUpdate(). Maybe if you post your code people can help you find it.